# Does Bender ever kill a human?

Tags: futurama

One of Bender's best known phrases, and a running joke of the series, is that he wants to 'Kill All Humans'.

Does he ever even kill one human?

I ask because I saw [Does Bender Ever Actually Kill A Human?](http://www.reddit.com/r/futurama/comments/12xizr/does_bender_ever_actually_kill_a_human/) (Reddit), and whilst there are some comments, none of them are overly convincing. I'm after something on camera, or strongly implied where he kills someone directly (not just destroying a building with people inside, or accidentally poisoning someone).

Comment: Well, Sledge Hammer talks all the time about shooting and killing people, yet...

Comment: He's been killing humans since before Fry got to the future: suicide booths, by proxy.

Answer (score 14):

In The Beast With a Billion Backs during the duel with Calculon we see that Bender's shot with the planetary annihilator ends up disintegrating a man in the middle of a doctor appointment.

He clearly did not survive.

Answer (score 10):

For all intents and purposes, Bender killed Fry in Bender's Big Score:

> Although Fry was actually a doomed doppelgänger and actually did survive (renaming himself Lars), this was unknown to Bender at that moment. Fry's "death" was *not* a collateral result of Bender destroying a building (like when he destroyed New York). He intended to kill Fry and was convinced that he succeeded.

Comment: Wasn't he also under the influence of the scammers' virus at the time though?

Comment: @Ash: Yes, he was. You could argue that doesn't count.

Comment: The question asks if has killed a human, not has he knowing attempted to kill a human and believed that he succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

He certainly tries to kill the professor in "Free will hunting". He shoots him right in the chest with a laser.

Comment: Trying isn't doing

Answer (score 2):

In *The Thief of Baghead*  Bender kills Fry by showing him an image of Langdon Cobb, after Cobb had warned him it would have 'terrible consequences'.

Unconvinced, he then goes on to show it to Amy and Hermes who suffer a similar fate.  Now convinced, he tries to show it to Zoidberg before Prof. Farnsworth stops him.

This does not prove a *murderous intent* specifically (ignoring Zoidberg's case), but more a callous disregard for their lives.

Comment: Note that he doesn't actually kill them... he just makes it so that their 'lifeforce' is temporarily sucked out.

Comment: @Dason  OK.. So they are only temporarily 'dead'.

Answer (score 0):

Bender is involved in the killing of [Dan McMasters](http://theinfosphere.org/Dan_McMasters). Somewhat also [Helmut Spargle](http://theinfosphere.org/Helmut_Spargle).

In [Decision 3012](http://theinfosphere.org/Decision_3012) you can see Bender with some kind of rifle, telling people to move together because he's low on bullets. Actually you don't see him shoot them - and it's an alternative reality (or not?).

Comment: Can cite anything here? Link to episode guide entries or even YouTube clips?

Comment: A citation would be helpful here.

Comment: I hope theinfosphere.org is a credible source for your research (: